# Why am I receiving downvotes when little has changed in my answering style?

Tags: support, downvotes, downvote-reason

I'm rather new to Stack Overflow. Basically, I have a style of answering questions which I've tried to describe below:

1. Though I've been exposed to a few languages, I restrict myself to the 'C' tag for now.
2. For most of my answers:

   1. I work out an answer in C code & test it on my computer. I save the code & execution details.
   2. I post my answer code on Stack Overflow.
   3. I post the execution details below my answer code on Stack Overflow.
   4. I don't exactly explain a lot in my answer (in plain English) for a variety of reasons:

      1. I don't wish to make my answers too long.
      2. I don't wish to harp on the mistakes of the question's author.
      3. I believe that posting execution details of my code allows me to connect better with the questions asked & prevents need for further explanation.
      4. I have other things to do, I can't spend more time on Stack Overflow.
3. Initially, as I answered questions, my reputation steadily increased. Seemed like people appreciated my answers. I did not mind the odd downvote even when I knew I had not been stingy in my answer (some people weren't satisfied with it, but as I said earlier, I don't have more time to spend on Stack Overflow).
4. Recently, I've received a string of downvotes on my answers. But my answer style hasn't changed & I've put in the usual effort. What's going on suddenly? Why have I received these downvotes? Am I really a good fit for Stack Overflow? If not, please tell me clearly - I'll invest my time & effort elsewhere.

Comment: If you compare your code answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67486080/578411) and the other answer that did get an upvote I assume you see some difference?

Comment: Do you check whether any similar questions exist where the answers address the same point and flag for closure as a duplicate? That should be the step before composing your own answer.

Comment: @rene: Yes, I do see a difference, thanks for pointing that out. I contribute other things in my answer that aren't mentioned by "Eric Postpischil" (who received an upvote there). But I will stop myself right now, I don't really want to argue with you or others since I've clearly explained my style in this question.

Comment: *"Try the code below"* - Why should I? If I don't understand the problem in the question, what makes you think your code will be understandable to me? If I can't tell by myself *why* your change works, then how useful is your proposal to me really? Put your mouse over the downvote button. See the popup that mentions the post not being useful? That's likely why your answer got downvoted.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Yes, I know I haven't checked if duplicates exist in every case (but that turns out to be just 1 in the 13 answers I've posted). When I bring up questions with the "C" tag, I check if others have marked as duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: @SiddharthaShivshankar Look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597982/error-invalid-conversion-from-const-char-to-char-when-trying-to-use-point/67599487#67599487), you add so much unnecessary code to the answer when in fact the only _useful_ change is from `char *subtopic` to `const char *subtopic`. You don't even explain the issue in your answer, compare that to the accepted answer there which clearly points out the issue. Plus a reader might even miss this change and wonder what exactly the problem was and what solved it.

Comment: You only throw fish at the OP to feed them. While charitable we prefer to teach an OP how to fish. That needs a tad more then: *Try this code*. Note that answers are primarily for future visitors. That the OP gets their problem solved is just a coincidence.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Usually it's because I've posted execution details below my code, so the question's author can see in 1 glance how my code solves their problem. That's what point 2.4.3 of this question says. Thanks.

Comment: "Execution details" do not explain code if one is not sufficiently versed in it. We are all telling you how your answer could be less useful than you think. If you aren't gonna heed the advice, then just accept you will be downvoted by folks who consider your answers not useful.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: Please see the output below my code. The question's author wasn't sure of their pointer arithmetic. My output clearly tells them what the strings, integers & pointers are and it makes the arithmetic obvious. Thanks.

Comment: @SiddharthaShivshankar that output does not tell anything much to me. What makes you think the OP did not know about pointer arithmetic etc.? From the OP's point of  view it likely looked like unrelated things. Plus as I said that extra unneeded code only serves to confuse the reader of what exactly _solved_ the problem. Not to mention the difference can be missed (since it is just one line in many) so it should be explicitly pointed out in the answer.

Comment: Without explanation and code comment the answer doesn't h LP people that have similar problems. Therefore it isn't helpful

Answer (score 23):

You’ve only been answering for about a month; your earlier experience was that you got lucky with who viewed your answers, is my guess. There is a huge variety in who looks at answers and can vote on those, from day to day, and you’d have to look at a much longer time period to draw any conclusions about changes in community reception of your answering style.

While we can’t ever be certain about *why* a given post received a downvote (voting is anonymous and doesn’t include motivation), I can make an educated guess, and you have already been told this in comments on some of your answers.

Your answers mostly just give code. Good, helpful answers tell you *what the problem was with the question* and *why the code solves that problem*. In other words: make your answers longer. Your answers are on the “too short” side.

Look at what answers have been well received. Learn by seeing what works well on the site. You’ll get the hang of it, just take the voting as general indicators of how useful your answers are. More downvotes than you expected -> see if there is anything you as a *visitor with the same problem* might want to find, and update accordingly.

And as an aside: we discourage adding greetings, taglines and other fluff to answers. Wishing someone “Good luck!” is nice but not part of an answer. Leave those out.

Comment: Thanks to you & others for the answer & comments respectively. It's crystal clear to me that I'm not a good fit for Stack Overflow now. Probably I will not contribute questions or answers in the future.

Comment: So instead of improving your answers your not going to submit any answers?

Comment: @SiddharthaShivshankar I’m not sure why you think that. You asked for feedback, which is great! All you have to do is take that feedback on board and adjust your answering style.

Comment: _“Learn by seeing what works well on the site.”_ — But also, learn from _recent_ examples. Single-sentence answers from 11 years ago with four-digit scores don’t count.